# Excel VBA: How to Find a Value in a Range of Columns and Move the Row Left 1

Tags: vba, excel

I run a daily report of our account details and the headers on the Excel file are always mis-aligned.  I would like a macro to help with this, but I am a beginner with macros and don't even know where to start.

On any active sheet, I would like to find a specific word in column B ("Trx Date") and move the row over 1 to the left.  The reports will always have the same column format, but the rows can fluctuate depending on the amount of detail.

"Trx Date" is the first header title, but it starts in column B and all the data starts in column A.  There is other information in column B so the word "Trx Date" would need to be found first.  Any ideas?  I am new to the site so it will not allow me to upload an image.  Thank you all!

This is what I was trying with no luck.....

```
Dim Firstrow As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim FinalRow As Long



With ActiveSheet.Select


    Firstrow = 7
    Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).row


    For FinalRow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1


        With .Cells(FinalRow, "B")

            If Not IsError(.value) Then

                Select Case .value
                Case Is = "Trx Date": .Offset(, -1).Delete Shift:=xlLeft
                End Select

            End If


        End With

    Next FinalRow

End With
```

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot example of the data? This I suspect will make it much easier to understand.

Comment: The best way to get help here is to first try something. If you get stuck, do some research, make an attempt at fixing things yourself, and only then ask a specific question about your attempts, showing what you have tried. Questions asking for complete solutions without demonstrating research effort usually get downvoted and closed.

Comment: If you have absolutely no idea where to start, using excel's built-in Macro Recorder can give you some ideas. The code that the macro recorder produces is generally very bad and shouldn't be used in production, but it can at least give you some ideas of how code for "find this value" or "move this column to the right" looks, which you can then refine.

Comment: Sorry, it would not allow me to produce a screen shot and I have tried making a case else statement, but not sure if I am even close to the right direction.  Record a macro seems like it would only work if the spreadsheet was always the same size.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
Dim Firstrow As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim FinalRow As Long

Firstrow = 7
Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

For FinalRow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1

    With Cells(FinalRow, 2)
        Select Case .Value
            Case "TRX Date": Cells(FinalRow, 1).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        End Select
    End With

Next FinalRow
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  When I ran the above, it would not do anything, but I was able to troubleshoot the original script that I had following what you used.  I kept everything the same, but I used your "Case "TRX Date": Cells(FinalRow, 1).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft" to produce my working results.